# PHP get value of char?

Tags: php

I have a single char, `$x[0]`. Now, I want to get an unsigned char from 0-255. How to do this?
Also, if I have 4 chars, `$x[0], $x[1], $x[2], $x[3]` I want to get an unsigned int from 0-2^32-1 out of those chars.

I hope I make sense. As a C programmer I am not sure those things are possible in PHP.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Could you please edit the question with more details and your attempts so far?

Comment: For example, if the character was 'A', you would want 65?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`ord`](http://php.net/ord) for a single byte and [`unpack`](http://php.net/unpack) for one or multiple bytes:

```
$byte = ord('A');
$dword = (ord('A') << 24) | (ord('B') << 16) | (ord('C') << 8) | ord('D');

$byte = current(unpack('c', 'A'));
$dword = current(unpack('N', 'ABCD'));
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you recommend doing these things with PHP or it's likely something will go wrong?

Comment: @We'reAllMadHere No, it should work as intended. Just remember that a character’s code point and the byte sequence with which it gets encoded with does not need to be the same and depends on the character encoding.

Answer (score 2):

If you are needing the ascii value of a character then you can use `ord()`

See demo [here](https://eval.in/107508)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't only need values from 0-127. I need from 0-255.